# Put latest RSS entry into iframe

Tags: iframe, dynamic, rss, feed

I'm new here and a bit of a noob. I know HTML and CSS basics, but trying to do something I suspect needs javascript...

I'm trying to create an iframe whose src defaults to the latest entry of an RSS Feed, with the feed itself below. Take a look at my code below and the link here http://visitrek.net/rssfeed/rssfeed.html

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dotnews.co.za%2FCode%2FRSS%2F515&chan=title&au=y&targ=newsiframe&utf=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dotnews.co.za%2FCode%2FRSS%2F515&chan=title&au=y&targ=newsiframe&utf=y&html=y">View RSS feed</a>
</noscript>
<div style="width:713px; overflow: hidden;"><iframe width="850px" height="2000px" frameborder="0" name="newsiframe" src="" scrolling="auto" style="-webkit-transform: scale(0.85); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;"</iframe></div>
```

Anyone have any bright ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a javascript function which targets your desired child Node in this case `li:nth-child(20)`, then get the `src` of the `InnerHtml` and update the `iframe src`.

Check out [Child elements in this link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/traversing-dom). I think that will point you in the write direction

Comment: I forgot to say. The function must run after the page is done loading